# Git still showing end of line characters

Tags: git, svn, eol

I just migrated an SVN repo to Git, and while inspecting the repo with `show` and `status` it shows `^M` on every line. For the moment no one else is using Git on my team so I can't ask them to `autocrlf` their commits, and nothing I try (.gitattributes, autocrlf, show -w etc) gets rid of that on output.

How do I get rid of that output when using `git show` and `git diff` ? I hope I don't have to redo a `git svn clone` with different settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, two seconds after posting this question I found my answer already.

Using `git config core.whitespace cr-at-eol` will fix this situation